# Where is the settings file located?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v

I usually render videos with Rockstar Editor, however rendering with everything on lowest settings and on 800x600 (bright side is I can play GTA V on GT820m) doesn't look that good. Changing all settings require a restart, which makes me restart game 2 times to render and go back to play. It takes some time to edit settings and restart so I just want to backup settings file etc.

Where is the settings files located?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `settings.xml` is found in `C:\Users\[YourWindowsUsername]\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V`

Answer (score 3):

The settings.xml is in (Copy-paste): `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Rockstar Games\GTA V`

I store my profile on a different drive.

USERPROFILE is a system environment variable pointing to a user's profile directory (Settings, Documents, Music, Photos, Desktop) More:[%USERPROFILE%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Examples)